# Improving question that follows MCVE guidelines?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Some time ago I posted this question: [Display another HTML in div from main HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47818063/display-another-html-in-div-from-main-html)

I believe it follows MCVE standards and I thought it was a decent question, but the downvotes tell a different story.

What can I add to improve this question?

Comment: The downvotes are probably because there is no good security reason to prohibit the use of iframes, and the person in your IT department doing this probably has no idea what they're talking about. If you want to embed a separate document from a different server, iframes are the way to go. It's akin to saying "I need to install a toilet bowl but my janitor says I can't use screws. Maybe I can do it using nails?"

Comment: Makes sense, but it's more like "The plumbing director wants me to install a toilet and he doesn't want me to use screws.". Regardless of what he knows, he is the boss, so I post a question looking for less-common alternatives. If anything, he should be the one getting the downvotes.

Comment: `If anything, he should be the one getting the downvotes.` Heh! Now that is certainly true. :) Questions with arbitrary-looking requirements that don't seem to make sense and complicate something that would be super easy to solve the normal way tend to be badly received on SO I'm afraid. Not sure whether anything can be done to work around that.

Comment: It may also be that questions like this are asked frequently. A quick search of that title brings up https://stackoverflow.com/q/14714085/215552, https://stackoverflow.com/q/12032664/215552, among others...

Comment: Its not a terrible question, but it is quite lacking in research effort. The basic answer is "Using one of the many modern techniques to compose a webpage out of components". One common method is to actually construct the front-end using javascript with frameworks such as Angular or React. But how can anyone provide such an answer factually as it is basically a crapshoot what you can and cannot use? Figuring out what to do is pretty much a you-problem, good luck and have fun browsing through the many possibilities of web app design.

Comment: @Gimby: It's not a great question, but I don't think it deserves 6 downvotes. Regardless, I would like to improve it. What do you suggest?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan, the problem is that I wasn't able to use an `iframe`. Regardless, I would like to improve it. What do you suggest?

Comment: My focus is improving this question. Any suggestions?

Comment: @rbhat There are several answers on those questions which do not revolve around an `iframe`. If none of those work, edit your question to include your attempts and explain why they didn't work for you. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates for more info

Comment: Thanks. I'll look at these answers and try them out.

Comment: Do you think that the question deserved 6 downvotes?

Comment: In any case, I'll try to improve the question. I don't believe it deserves 6 downvotes and I'm almost certain it won't be upvoted even after I make the changes.